# Connect a local node to the Rococo Parachain Network

Tags: parachain, substrate-node, rococo, libp2p, peers

Issue: 
Currently, I have a parachain and a relay chain running on Rococo testnet locally. I'm having trouble connecting my node to the parachain network (0 peers to 1 peer).

Goal: 
I'm trying to connect my libp2p node to the parachain network, with the indication of +1 peer in the parachain network. I'm at a crossroads with how to implement my node as "Alive" or "IsOnline" in the parachain Rococo network.

Method: 
I'm trying to use local mechanisms to discover peers and connect to the parachain network, using mdns and dht. However, I can't tell if I'm implementing the methods properly.

Confusion: 
Peer Routing isn't able to locate closestPeers using the 'key'. I'm having trouble with discovering myself on the parachain network.

My libp2p configuration: 
const options = { 
peerId: peerId, 
addresses: { 
listen: ['/ip4/192.168.1.212/tcp/0/ws'] 
}, 
transports: [ 
tcp(), 
webSockets(), 
], 
connectionEncryption: [noise()], 
streamMuxers: [yamux(), mplex()], 
peerDiscovery: [ 
mdns(), 
new kadDHT({ 
kBucketSize: 20 
}) 
], 
services: { 
identify: identify(), 
ping: ping({ 
protocolPrefix: 'ipfs', 
interval: 10000, 
timeout: 10000, 
}), 
kadDHT: kadDHT({ 
clientMode: false, 
kBucketSize: 20 
}) 
}, 
config: { 
peerDiscovery: { 
autoDial: true, 
mdns: { 
interval: 10000, 
enabled: true 
}, 
kadDHT: { 
kBucketSize: 20, 
enabled: true, 
randomWalk: { 
enabled: true, 
interval: 300e3, 
timeout: 10e3 
}
}
},
}, 
connectionManager: { 
autoDial: true, 
maxConnections: 1000, 
minConnections: 10, 
dialTimeout: 10000, 
}, 
}

Lastly, these are the trace logs from the parachain network. 
[Parachain] Adding a new known peer 
[Parachain] Known peer (Outbound) dropped from SetId(0) 
[Parachain] Peer disconnected, reputation: -256 to -256 
**Immediate drop in connection after trying to add a new known peer**

**I apologize in advance for the terrible formatting**

Answer (score 0):

Need a little more information…

Are you using the cumulus pallet?
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/docs/overview.md

As far as I know, a special transaction is required to update a runtime to a parachain, via Cumulus.

Here’s an excellent guide for deploying a functional Parachain.
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk